# How can I prevent double file uploading with Amazon S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, amazon-s3

I decided to use Amazon S3 for document storage for an app I am creating.  One issue I run into is while I need to upload the files to S3, I need to create a document object in my app so my users can perform CRUD actions.

One solution is to allow for a double upload.  A user uploads a document to the server my Rails app lives on.  I validate and create the object, then pass it on to S3.  One issue with this is progress indicators become more complicated.  Using most out-of-the-box plugins would show the client that file has finished uploading because it is on my server, but then there would be a decent delay when the file was going from my server to S3.  This also introduces unnecessary bandwidth (at least it does not seem necessary)

The other solution I am thinking about is to upload the file directly to S3 with one AJAX request, and when that is successful, make a second AJAX request to store the object in my database.  One issue here is that I would have to validate the file after it is uploaded which means I have to run some clean up code in S3 if the validation fails.

Both seem equally messy.

Does anyone have something more elegant working that they would not mind sharing?  I would imagine this is a common situation with "cloud storage" being quite popular today.  Maybe I am looking at this wrong.

Comment: I have asked a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796468/amazon-s3-multipart-upload-with-plupload-and-rails-3  Question is similar because I am trying to solve the same problem, but i thought of an approach to use chunking to eliminate the double time.  Is your application on EC2?  Mine is, but it is still slow to resave the large file.

Answer (score 2):

Unless there's a particular reason not to use paperclip I'd highly recommend it. Used in conjunction with delayed job and delayed paperclip the user uploads the file to your server filesystem where you perform whatever validation you need. A delayed job then processes and stores it on s3. Really, really easy to set up and a better user experience.