# Amazon S3 Multipart Upload with plupload and Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, amazon-s3, plupload

Amazon has multipart upload functionality where you can send a file in chunks and get it assembled on S3.  This allows for some nice resume like functionality for uploading to S3.  From another question i got this nice link: [Rails 3 & Plupload](http://neovintage.blogspot.com/2010/06/file-uploads-with-rails-3-plupload-and.html)

My question is does anyone have any examples where they used the plupload chunking feature with the Amazon multipart feature?  Ideally with carrierwave & fog.

I can see it doing the following:

- Generate Unique ID for the upload with plupload,
  can we do an event when the plupload 
  starts?
- Attaching an ajax request to 
  the chunk completed with the ID
- Having ajax controller method on the 
  server which uploads to s3 using the 
  ID
- when all are complete fire a
  controller action to reassemble

There is supposedly some PHP code which does some combining, but not with S3 and i can't stand to read PHP.

Comment: Hey, having the same need here! Did you finally find something? Let me know

Comment: No this is on the back burner for now.  Don't think anyone has done it.  I could probably write it, would take time, but I don't know how to make it generic enough to release as a rails plugin.

Comment: Plupload actually doesn't support this yet.  They are hoping to have a Java based one in the future that will do this though:  http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=585

Comment: @Amala, got any luck in this.. i am also looking for the same, if you find something useful, let me know...

Comment: Looking for the same functionality. For now I'm using Uploadify to post to S3...

Answer (score 2):

[this is very similar, you should find Interesting](https://github.com/lgs/mp3upload)

enjoy & feel free to fork/pull request ... & so on

Answer (score 0):

You can find simple core java code without AWS library, This will help u implement in any technology..
http://dextercoder.blogspot.in/2012/02/multipart-upload-to-amazon-s3-in-three.html